# ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING on Chrome when providing dynamic image content on HttpResponse

Tags: java, google-chrome, httpresponse

When providing dynamic image content on the HTTP Response,
I faced the issue that Chrome (and only Chrome) to return the

> net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING error.

This was the script:

```
void DownloadImage() {
   HTTPRESPONSE().setHeader('Cache-Control', '');
   HTTPRESPONSE().setHeader('Pragma', '');
   If NotEmpty($media.mimeType) Then
      HTTPRESPONSE().setHeader('Content-Type', $media.mimeType);
   End
   HTTPRESPONSE().setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=' & $media.name);
   If $httpResponseOutputStream == null Then
      $httpResponseOutputStream := HTTPRESPONSE().getOutputStream();
   End
   CopyFileToStream($media.path, $httpResponseOutputStream);
}
```

So the image was not displayed in Google Crome.

The fix however was to flush and close the Output Stream at the end.

```
void DownloadImage() {
    ...
    $httpResponseOutputStream.flush();
    $httpResponseOutputStream.close();
}
```